# git lfs call failing App Center

Tags: visual-studio-app-center

My build step is failing in "App Center" because of git lfs. Thing is in our regular builds (even Jenkins) we never use git lfs and when we use App Center, I think we are forced to use the agent which then uses lfs.

My questions are
- What can we do to prevent git lfs being called by the agent ?
- If the answer to the previous question is No, is there a way to specify our own git commands for pulling the source ?

```
Starting Hosted Agent
##[section]Starting: Job
##[section]Starting: Initialize job
Current agent version: '2.138.6'
```

:::::

```
##[command]git lfs fetch origin e5d5057ddcf11401b8a3b17fcc32e1601a8909a36c
fetch: Fetching reference e5d5057ddcf11401b8a3b17fcc32e1601a8909a36c
Could not scan for Git LFS files
```

After a bunch of retries, this is the error message shown in App Center

```
Client IP addresses:
10.79.0.250
fe80::5028:c1aa:122:c80f
##[error]System.InvalidOperationException: Git lfs fetch failed with exit code: 2. Git lfs logs returned with exit code: 0.
   at Agent.Plugins.Repository.GitSourceProvider.<GetSourceAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Agent.Plugins.Repository.CheckoutTask.<RunAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Agent.PluginHost.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: Have you found any solution for this. I am also facing this problem.

Comment: @BasitAli - It's been a while but it ultimately turned out to be an App Center issue. AppCenter has it's own git setup which is problematic. Your best bet is to contact support (they are very responsive) and ask them as to why AppCenter is querying gitlfs even though you don't have anything in gitlfs